# Recurring router problems

Tags: networking, router, dns, internet

I just moved to a new flat and got a new LTE router with a new ISP. The contract includes (but does not guarantee) 80MBits DownStream and 40 MBits UpStream. I have managed to get up to 40 or 50 Mbits some time, so the router and the connection the ISP via LTE seems to work just fine.
Now to my problem:
Even though the connection seems to be up (checked by running a speed test on speedtest.net), some of my devices cannot resolve certain internet pages.
For instance I have an amazon fire tv stick, which is streaming Netflix for 2 or 3 hours without any troubles and suddenly the internet connection cannot be established any more.
On several other occasions my laptop works fine and can resolve any webpage I was visiting for like 5 hours, and suddenly a webpage (rs-online.com to be exakt) wont load any more, even though it did like 4 minutes ago. I checked on my cellphone, and yes: the page is available.

For all problems the only fix I found was to restart the router (either power cycle or restart on the router's webpage). That fix may be acceptable if problems like this arise only every other week or once a month, but certainly not if I have to restart the router 2 or 3 times a day. As you might imagine this is kinda annoying!
Sadly I have no idea what to look for to find the error. I tried to change the DNS server to 8.8.8.8 instead of 192.168.0.1 on the fire tv stick, which didnt resolve the problem.
If it is helpful, i could provide wireshark traffic recordings of the wifi network.

About my setup:
I am using a 3Tube Router with the HW Version PCBMF282V1.0.0; FW Version: BD_H3GATZM8630V1.0.0B14; SW Version: CR_H3GATMF282V1.0.1B02 which seems to be a MF282 by ZTE with a ISP branding to 3.
Before that I was using a E5576-320 mobile wifi router by Huawei which showed the exact same problem, only with lower down/upstream.

If anybody could point me into the right direction I would be very grateful!

Kind regards

Chris

Comment: I would say it's highly likely your isp is hijacking dns requests and blocking traffic which it thinks is excessive. If you have Linux, I would tend to try `dig -t a +trace www.google.com` and see if it contacts the root servers. Or it could be the router has malware. Or...

Comment: Note: I also can't reach rs-online.com, at least that has nothing to do with your network.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.
The problem seemed to be the ISP who was seemingly blocking the internet connection to certain pages from time to time. I changed the ISP and now it is working as intended.
The webpage rs-online.com is only reachable if you add the first level domain at.rs-online.com to the URL. So I made an error when I wrote the error description.