# Recurring issue of random websites experiencing timeouts in home network until router reset

Tags: router, isp, timeout

I am encountering a networking issue for many years now, and mysteriously the only common factor across these years is... me. Which doesn't make any sense, so I've finally decided to ask here.

So, the problem is that at random times (but sometimes several times per day!) random websites become unreachable in my home network. Connection simply times out. Restarting the router helps (and is the only thing I found that actually helps).

- It happens on all devices (my computer, my girlfriend's computer, my phone, my smart TV, ...). So, it can't be the device or operating system.
- It happened also already many years ago when I had different laptops and phones and printers than I have now. So it can't be a particular device in my network causing the issue either.
- It happens at the actual connection to the target server, not during DNS resolution. It happens regardless of DNS settings (router DNS, Google DNS, CloudFlare DNS, ...) and also when I try to connect to the IP manually. Also I did check that the IP is correct and not coming from a bad DNS resolution. So, it can't be a DNS problem.
- It's not always the same website. Sometimes it's something more prominent like Discord or Slack or YouTube, sometimes it's something odd and specific like `ib.dkb.de` (while `www.dkb.de` works) or some internal cloud server I'm developing software for. So, it can't be a particular server blocking my IP or whatever.
- In some cases it happens the first time I ever visited that page (like in the `ib.dkb.de` example). So, it can't come from a high number of accesses to the same server.
- When it happens, it affects any connection to a given IP address, regardless on which port (including SSH for example).
- I had this problem both in my current apartment as well as in my previous apartment (200km apart). So, it can't be related to my location.
- I had this problem both with my current ISP (Drei) as well as with my previous ISP (A1). So, it can't be my ISP.
- I had this problem both with a 5G router (current apartment) as well as with DSL/broadband routers (previous apartment), in total three different devices. So it can't be the particular router or the type of connection.
- I never had this issue with my phone's Internet connection, even when tethered over Wi-Fi to the computer. I also never had it with my laptop's built-in LTE modem, both of which use the same ISP as my home network right now (Drei). I did have the issue both with LAN and Wi-Fi connections to my router though. That would indicate it only happens when a router is involved, but it's not related to whether Wi-Fi is used or not.
- A friend of mine who has the same ISP, same router and same contract does not experience any issues.

As you can see, it seems almost as if a ghost haunts just *me*, all other factors are interchangeable here, I was not able to pin down any common factor other than having some sort of router involved and an Internet contract with my name on it!

I have already called my ISPs (the previous one as well as this one) multiple times. They gave me all kinds of generic responses like making sure my Wi-Fi signal is stable. One time, I reached a more technical person who was able to remotely check some "debug logs" and said everything looked perfectly fine. It was suggested to make sure my router's firmware is up to date, but it is every time I check (auto-update is enabled).

When I ran `tracert` on an affected IP, it gets stuck usually one or two hops after my router's IP, at some host that includes my ISP's name. However, I had this issue with two different ISPs and also both 5G and DSL/broadband, and a friend of mine who has the exact same ISP and router does not have this issue.

My current router model is a 5G router provided by Drei but made by ZTE. The web interface nowhere shows a model number and the sticker on the device just says "Model: DreiMaxx".

Do you have any idea what could be going on here? I'm out of ideas.

<sub>This is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1706148/recurring-router-problems) but I had the issue with two ISPs...</sub>

Comment: I'd have a look at https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/ for starters. It's a common enough cause that it's not totally surprising it can happen on two different units.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I ran the test and the [result](https://www.waveform.com/tools/bufferbloat?test-id=4844b669-9aff-4965-afef-40aa63cbb2bf) suggests that there is a bit of bufferbloat but it should not affect normal use (+160ms isn't that much). So far I don't understand how this could result in my issue unless it would cause a 60,000ms+ "latency" resulting in the timeouts, and that only for a certain target IP address (because connecting to other servers doesn't have problems in that case)...

Comment: You haven't remarked on whether you have (1) Tested different browsers, (2) Had at the time some background job accessing the internet, (3) Tried to disable your firewall or security software.

Comment: Thank you, however 1) is irrelevant due to my comment about different devices (including phones and smart TVs) as well as the fact that `tracert` also can't reach the IP - and it's not just port 443, it also affected SSH for example, but you are right I didn't mention the last fact though (added now); 2) maybe sometimes I have, maybe sometimes I haven't, it's hard to tell whether for example my phone was downloading an update; 3) as with #1, this is irrelevant because it affects all kinds of different devices.

Comment: Could it be the IP is being blocked, and restarting the router gets a new IP? If you have a machine with malware, for example, that's part of DDoS net, your IP may be blocked. To test, turn off **all** devices, including phones, monitor cameras and other IoT devices except for one, and see if the issue is (temporarily) resolved. Then start up half, to find out on which half of devices is the issue, then 1/4, then 1/8...

Comment: Interesting thought. I don't have any devices in use now which would also have been in used 7 years ago though, when I started experiences this issue. Still - I think it will be easiest to start by checking IP address before and after restart next time it happens, so I can see whether that would even make sense. If it does, I can continue bisecting devices (which of course is a lot more effort). Thank you

Comment: I was unable to figure it out and switched to a different setup in which I use the same modem as before, but only as modem in bridge mode, and I use a TP-Link AC1750 with OpenWRT on it as main router. No more troubles! Maybe the modem-router-thingies from the Internet providers in Austria are just all crap, who knows.